# Querying across relationships in a template

Tags: templating, database, query, queries

I have two Sections on my site: Country and Alert. The Alert section has a relation with Country via an "Entries" field. An Alert represents something that is happening in a particular country for a period of time so it will have a post date and an expiry date.

In my template, I want to show a list of the 5 Countries that have currently active Alerts (ideally ordered by the country with the latest Alert).

I'm not sure how query across relationships in Craft (outside of using the `relatedTo` query, but that only allows you to related to one entry, not a number of entries)? It seems all relationships are handled in a separate `relation` table in the DB.

How can I achieve an query such as this within a Craft template?

Comment: One option is to create a loop and start to assemble the logic there, but this requires introducing 1-query per iteration which can easily get out of hand. I notice Craft offers Eager-loading https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/eager-loading-elements.html but does this extend to relationships between Sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is one solution I've come up with, which seems to work and (I think) avoids 1+ queries:

```
{% set groups = craft.entries({
    section: 'alert',
    with: [
        'country',
    ]
}).orderBy('postDate desc').status('live').all() | group(alert => alert.country[0]) %}
<ul>
    {% for country, alerts in groups | slice(0, 5) %}
        <li>
            {{ country }} <!-- Cannot use country Entry -->
            <ul>
                {% for alert in alerts %}
                    <li>{{ alert.title }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I would prefer being able to handle this entirely in queries though

Comment: One problem here is that by using the `group` filter you lose access to the underlying Entry and can only make use of the string you group on.

Answer (score 1):

It's from the top of my head here so no idea if this is going to work, but my idea is:

- Get all active alerts order by postDate (just their ID's to make it faster)
- Retrieve all related countries and take the first 5 (You can do a relatedTo with more than 1 entry.)

```
{% set alerts = craft.entries({
    section:    'alert',
    orderBy:    'postDate desc',
    status:     'live'
}).ids() %}

{% set countries = craft.entries({
    section:    'countries',
    relatedTo:  alerts,
    limit:      5
}).all() %}
```